# cmake regex.c issue in cygwin with mapserver

Tags: regex, cmake, cygwin, mapserver

I try to install mapserver-6.4.1 in cygwin 32-bit, but it gives an error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:233 (add_library): 
  Cannot find source file: 

    //regex.c 

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp 
  .hxx .in .txx
```

In my system, regex.c is in:

```
$ locate regex.c | grep /usr
/usr/src/debug/a2ps-4.14-3/src/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/bind-9.9.5-3/lib/isc/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/binutils-2.24.51-5/libiberty/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/cygwin64-gcc-4.8.3-1/libiberty/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/cygwin64-gcc-4.8.3-1/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/regex.cc
/usr/src/debug/emacs-24.3-2/src/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/enscript-1.6.4-4/compat/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/flex-2.5.39-1/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/gcc-4.8.3-2/libiberty/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/gcc-4.8.3-2/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/regex.cc
/usr/src/debug/gdb-7.8-1/libiberty/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/gettext-0.18.3.2-2/gettext-tools/libgrep/m-regex.c
/usr/src/debug/glib2.0-2.38.2-3/glib/gregex.c
/usr/src/debug/glibmm2.4-2.38.1-1/glib/glibmm/regex.cc
/usr/src/debug/grep-2.16-1/gnulib-tests/test-regex.c
/usr/src/debug/grep-2.16-1/lib/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/m4-1.4.17-1/lib/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/mc-4.8.12-1/lib/search/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/metis-5.1.0-1/GKlib/gkregex.c
/usr/src/debug/mingw64-i686-gcc-4.8.3-1/libiberty/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/mingw64-i686-gcc-4.8.3-1/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/regex.cc
/usr/src/debug/mingw64-x86_64-gcc-4.8.3-1/libiberty/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/mingw64-x86_64-gcc-4.8.3-1/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/regex.cc
/usr/src/debug/ncurses-5.9-20140524-1/form/fty_regex.c
/usr/src/debug/openmpi-1.7.5-1/orte/util/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/pl-6.4.1-3/packages/xpce/src/txt/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/sed-4.2.2-3/lib/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/w3m-0.5.3-2/regex.c
/usr/src/debug/xedit-1.2.1-1/lisp/regex.c
```

Any idea how to solve this?

ps. $ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.3-WOW64 gery 1.7.32(0.274/5/3) 2014-08-13 23:03 i686 Cygwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it basically was to change this:

```
-DCMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=1
```

to

```
-DCMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=0
```

so, I used:

```
cmake .. -DWITH_OGR=0 -DWITH_GDAL=0 -DWITH_WCS=0 -DWITH_WFS=0 -DCMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=0
```

and Mapserver compiled flawlessly.